# jasperreport renders empty pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Have:
- a report generator class (Test.class). This class populates an  JRBeanArrayDataSource with dummy non-empty values.

- a javabean (OficioSipoData)
- a simple report

All i get is a blank pdf.

- Checked for exceptions. main() method throws nothing
- The  list of values passed to the DataSource is not empty.

Thanks

The classes:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Test t = new Test();
        try {
            t.dostuff();
        } catch (JRException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void dostuff() throws JRException, IOException {        
        Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();                              
        File f = new File("C:\\report1.jrxml");
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f); 
        JasperReport jrsub = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fis);


        List<OficioSipoData> l = new ArrayList<OficioSipoData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            addDummyOSD(l,i);
        }       

        Object[] os = l.toArray();
        JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(os);        
        JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jrsub, params, ds);
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jrsub, params, ds);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\report1.pdf"));
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("fine");
    }

    private void addDummyOSD(List<OficioSipoData> lista, int i) {
        OficioSipoData osd = new OficioSipoData();
        osd.setDireccion("asasa " + i);
        osd.setFecha("11/11/2013");
        osd.setOperativo("dsdsds" + i);
        lista.add(osd);
    }           
}


public class OficioSipoData {
    private String fecha;
    private String direccion;
    private String operativo;

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }
    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getOperativo() {
        return operativo;
    }
    public void setOperativo(String operativo) {
        this.operativo = operativo;
    }
}
```

The JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c79c5925-d8ca-40e8-bad2-1eaadb05c38f">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="direccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fecha" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="113" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e412065c-5a73-462f-9390-0096e54f80b3" x="226" y="23" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[wiii]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="ffc0130b-fee2-4861-b33a-a1078456813f" x="216" y="13" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[waaa]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="132" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e34f4c70-8e1c-405b-b3f7-90e11e5e9b7e" x="0" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[direccion]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ab77eb85-4dfa-44da-aa5e-3ad98b7b426e" x="100" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{direccion}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called the method [`JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperReport ,  java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, JRDataSource)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperRunManager.html#runReportToPdf%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29) twice.

And this is *wroing* because during first call the engine has already iterated the collection. You can check the result of `JRDataSource.next()` method before second call of `JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf` method.

Your right code will be:

```
private void dostuff() throws JRException, IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    File f = new File("C:\\report1.pdf");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    JasperReport jrsub = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fis);

    List<OficioSipoData> l = new ArrayList<OficioSipoData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        addDummyOSD(l, i);
    }

    byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jrsub, params, 
            new JRBeanArrayDataSource(l.toArray()));
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(""C:\\report1.pdf""));
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("fine");
}
```

---

You can see [JavaBean Data Sources](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#javabeandatasources) sample and other samples (distributed with *JasperReports* library package - `jasperreports-x.y.z\demo\samples\` folder) of using Exporters for optimizing your code.